# Android: adding progress bars?

Tags: java, android

What would be the best way to use a progress dialog in the following circumstance..

```
 //start progress dialog here.
 RequestInfoFormServer();
 ProcessThatInfo();
 return;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using, if you're not already using, an `AsyncTask` to do all the long running tasks in the background.
You can also use a service to handle all of your Internet stuff if you plan to do a lot of Internet actions.

1) Construct a `Progress Dialog` with

```
ProgressDialog progressDiaog = new ProgressDialog();
```

study this constructor and the methods for more customization
For a better UX, if you set the dialog to be cancell-able, then you should also be canceling the network activity if the dialog box is cancelled.

2) Create an `AsyncTask`. in its `onPreExecute()` method, use the following to display the progress dialog:

```
progressDialog.show();
```

3) In `doInBackground()`, do all of your web stuff:

```
 RequestInfoFormServer();
 ProcessThatInfo(); //I hope this doesn't have to do with the UI
 return;
```

4) Then in `onPostExecute()`
    - do all the stuff that's to be done on the UI
    - close the progress dialog box with `progressDialog.cancel()` if you don't have to show the same dialog box again.

Revert if you jump into any other issue.

Comment: Overwhelming response. I have decided to clear all the clutter from my answer and provide some more information. going to edit now.